# "Failed to Load Resource Error" despite file being in directory

Tags: javascript, html

I'm programming a project using HTML and JavaScript. I access my js code with the following script tags:

```
 <script src="js/monthChanger.js"></script>
```

However, when running my program in Edge & Google Chrame, I keep getting
[this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fk7md.png)

Why is this happening? Looking at my [file directories](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkVHq.png) there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the way I declared the function.

Comment: try `<script src="../js/monthChanger.js"></script>`

Comment: Welcome to SO! It is preferred to not post screenshots of errors, code, structures, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[check out this article on absolute and relative paths](https://beamtic.com/paths)

you probably want this:

`<script src="./js/monthChanger.js"></script>`

The `./` makes it relative to the current folder.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, so it turns out my issue had nothing to do with HTML.

I didn't specify this in the OP, but I was also using a Django's framework in my project. I had mistakenly assumed that static fields such as css, js, and images would be called the same way they are called in normal html files. However, after reading django's [documentation on managing static files](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/), I realize that this is not the case. I follow django's instructions and was able to get my code working.